# Rounding a Positive or Negative Number

Tags: c++, floating-point, integer, rounding, negative-number

I need to do rounding on a number, but I don't know whether that number is negative or positive.

Is there a better way to round `foo` that to do this:

```
static_cast<int>(foo > 0 ? foo + 0.5 : foo - 0.5)
```

Basically I want this behavior:

> 3.4 => 3
>   3.5 => 4
>   -3.4 => -3
>   -3.5 => -4

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For C++ there is one: [`std::lround`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round)

Comment: I know this extends the question but is there any way to do this pre-c++11?

Comment: I'm accepting this answer, however I'd like to note that [Glenn Teitebaum's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31163962/2642059) is a good solution if you do not have access to C++11 or more simply just do `static_cast<int>(foo + 0.5 - (foo < 0.0))`.

Answer (score 4):

Going back to old school C tricks that count on `bool` converting to 1 if `true` and 0 if `false`:

```
 static_cast <int>(foo + 0.5 - (foo < 0.0))
```

You should generally use library functions, but you can performance test against this if it is a critical section

Comment: I like the idea of using a condition, but not branching on it. But I think we can do better than your solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31162992/rounding-a-positive-or-negative-number#comment50369982_31163049

Comment: @JonathanMee Mind if i update the solution to show your simplified math?

Comment: Nope, sounds great. It would be good to have the simplified math as a solution.

Answer (score 1):

In C math library, there is,

```
double round  (double x);
```

or there is,

```
double nearbyint  (double x);
```

Comment: These are good options but they still require me to `static_cast`. `lround` also puts the value in integer format.

Comment: Besides `round ` (double), there's also `roundf` (float), and `roundl` (long double).